# selenium multithreading, is this the right way to open 5 chrome browsers without causing any issues for webdriver instances?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, thread-safety

is this the right way to open 5 chrome browsers without causing any issues for webdriver instances?
I want my code to be thread safe, what do you guys think?

```
import threading
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Function to open a browser and perform actions
def open_browser_and_do_stuff(thread_num):
    # Initialize a new WebDriver instance for this thread
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    try:
        # Perform actions with this WebDriver instance
        driver.get("https://www.example.com")
        search_box = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        search_box.send_keys("Thread " + str(thread_num))
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Thread {thread_num} encountered an error: {str(e)}")
    finally:
        # Ensure the WebDriver instance is properly closed
        try:
            driver.quit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Thread {thread_num} encountered an error while quitting: {str(e)}")

# Number of threads (browsers) to open
num_threads = 5

# Create and start threads
threads = []

for i in range(num_threads):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=open_browser_and_do_stuff, args=(i + 1,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

# Wait for all threads to complete
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print("All threads have completed.")
```

Solution for webdriver instances

Comment: Follow this video, where Naveen explain the utilization of the thread-local concept in selenium to work on multiple browser  -   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_MI4hStoW0

Comment: Looks okay to me. Instead do `for i in range(1, num_threads + 1)` and then you do not need to add 1 to each `i` value as in `thread = ... args=(i,))`?